# Cron job to delete files older than x days?

Tags: linux, crontab

I'm currently using this cron job to delete stalled temp files in a particular location. How can I improve this to only delete files older than x days (e.g., 30 days)?

`0 4 * * 0 /bin/rm -fv /home/*/tmp/Cpanel_*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find /home/*/tmp/Cpanel_*' -type f \! -newermt "month ago" -delete
```

`find` can be tricky, so do your homework reading about it and test well. The common practice is to test with a command that doesn't act on found targets, like `ls` or `echo`. `find` has some builtin commands you can use for testing. So you can start with this:

```
 find /home/*/tmp/Cpanel_*' -type f \! -newermt "month ago" -ls
```

Comment: Good answer. For more efficiency you could use the fact that `find` can have any number of directories _or files_ before the first option, as in: `find /home/*/tmp/Cpanel_* !-newermt "month ago" -delete`; you can add `-maxdepth 0` to ensure that only the files from the shell expansion are deleted, without descending any directories (probably not relevant here).

Comment: I am getting this message: `-bash: !-newermt: event not found` any idea what it means?

Comment: @IMB It means you are using Bash and it can't find the entry in its history. You don't need Bash. Use `find` as the command.

Comment: @IMB Or maybe not... There needs to be a break between `!` and `-`. See updated line above.

Comment: @IMB And in fact it should be `\! -newrmt`.

Comment: I am getting a warning: `find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name `*/tmp/Cpanel_*'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `*/tmp/Cpanel_*''.`

Comment: @IMB I messed this up a lot. See my answer updated. It should be ok now (I GUESS). Be carefull....

Comment: @IMB I also added `-type f` to find files only.